# Script can access SQLite database in ~/Library when run from Terminal, but not when run from launchd

Tags: mac, launchd

I have a script that processes my screen time data using the SQLite database `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Knowledge/knowledgeC.db`. The script runs fine when I launch it manually via Terminal, but I want to run it on a schedule via `launchd`. When it runs in `launchd` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 31, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
sqlite3.DatabaseError: authorization denied
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is protected from automated access by Transparency, Consent, and Control. To remove that protection you have to grant Full Disk Access to the Python interpreter in the Security and Privacy settings. You must already have done that for the Terminal app.

Comment: For those who find this answer, I didn't have much success adding the python interpreter to Full Disk Access, or zsh, or launchd and launchctl. Eventually I used fdautil from this product https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/ and it worked.